# How do I get string length of an element after binding using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ok what I am trying to do is count the number of characters inside an element, but the element includes binding (eg. {{data.username}}) and I want to get the string length **after** the binding occurs.

My thinking so far has been to create a attribute directive and just `.text().length` the element that is passed into the "link" function — see below:

This was my working so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Counting Characters</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div count-chars>{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}</div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);

      app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.person = {
          firstName: "James",
          lastName: "Smith"
        };
      });

      app.directive('countChars', [function(){
        return {
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(elem.text());
            console.log(elem.text().length);
          }
        };
      }]);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this only returns the string before any bindings occurs (via the `console.logs`s at the moment). What I would want to get is `James Smith` and `11` characters, but what I get is `{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}` and `40` chars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing you can do is to wrap your code into `$timeout` service, so it will execute on the next digest loop, which means that all interpolation job will have finished by that time:

```
app.directive('countChars', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(elem.text());
                console.log(elem.text().length);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vkQoTPmx0gL3hOUpN0n?p=preview

Comment: While this does work for the use-case at hand, it is limited by two assumptions. First, that the values are going to be assigned in the current "thread". It breaks if the values are assigned asynchronously. Second, that the values are assigned only once and then never changed.

Comment: @hon2a I know, that's why I said this is simplest this in this case. More generic solution if we need to track updates/changes would use `scope.$watch` of course like in your example or Mike Chamberlain.

Comment: Yeah, I just added the comment to make the answer more comprehensive by including drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your directive, could you calculate `elem.text().length` inside a `$watch` on `person.firstName + person.lastName`?

Comment: Also true, you can use `$watch`. However it's preffered to avoid additional watches, and this one will have DOM manipulation inside, so it's not very good for performance. But it's possible, true.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the interpolated string during compilation, as you're only assigning the values later, in the controller. Therefore, you need to watch for the changes:

```
compile: function (element) {
    var text = $interpolate(element.text());

    return function link ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch(text, function (interpolatedText) {
            // measure and log (or do whatever with) your interpolated text
            // (the code you put here will run whenever the text changes)
        });
    };
}
```

(I've put retrieval of the original text in *compile* phase, so that it works even if the properties on scope are already assigned.)

Comment: Very nice usage of `$interpolate`, +1.